# How can I use chrome.enterprise.platformKeys on a Chrome extension for Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I've been trying to generate a custom client certificate on Chrome OS for things like VPN.

No matter what I do, I keep getting that `chrome.enterprise.platformKeys` is undefined.

I've been creating test extensions in Developer mode on my managed Chrome OS machine. I see on the documentation page here it says:

```
Note: This API is only for extensions pre-installed by policy.
```

How can I properly use this API, if I want to test apps in Developer mode?

Comment: Try starting chrome with `--whitelisted-extension-id=yourextensionid`. See [how to do it in ChromeOS](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags#TOC-Chrome-OS).